# Javascript breaks after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a list of items. When one is clicked, I use javascript to show a dropdown of more information.

The javascript works for the initial items, but when I dynamically load new items on this page using ajax, it stops.

At the moment, the Javascript is placed in the footer. I've tried placing it in different places in the code but to no avail. No errors show up in the console either.

I'm following the w3schools accordion tutorial here (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp), and I'm using infinte scroll from Meta Fizzy (https://infinite-scroll.com/)

HTML

```
<ul class="item-listings">
<li class="item">
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
</li>
```

Javascript

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.parentNode.classList.toggle("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Ajax

```
<script>
jQuery(function(a){a("ul.item-listings").infiniteScroll({path:".next",append:"li.item",button:".view-more-button",scrollThreshold:!1,loadOnScroll:!1,hideNav:".pagination",history:!1,status:".page-load-status",checkLastPage:!0});var b=a(".view-more-button");a=a("ul.item-listings");var c=!1;a.on("request.infiniteScroll",function(a,c){b.hide()});a.on("load.infiniteScroll",function(a,d,e,f){c||b.show()});a.on("last.infiniteScroll",function(a,d,e){b.hide();c=!0})});
</script>
```

I'm not really sure what to do. Is there a way to reload this everytime I make the ajax call, or could my javascript be changed in some way? I thought that because it used a click event listener it would be fine, but sadly not.

Comment: Are you applying event listeners to the newly downloaded items? You do not have code for that in the question so it's hard to see where your problem is.

Comment: No. I'm not sure how to do that? All the new items are structured exactly the same in html.

It's just the code I have here. The html and then javascript in the footer on my webpage.

Comment: _"It's just the code I have here"_ - Nothing in _"the code"_ adds new elements or triggers an ajax request so this cannot be the complete relevant code -> [mcve]

Comment: Ok I'll update with ajax code

Comment: Updated now. Should mention I'm using infinite scroll from meta fizzy (infinite-scroll.com)

Comment: Aa you are using jQuery already, not quite sure why you bother with pure javascript addEventListener. Maybe, you can achieve your goals using `.on` from jQuery by catching all events at the <body> Docs: https://api.jquery.com/on/ - see the last demo on that page, where dynamical elements are added.

Comment: I know what you mean but I don't have a clue how to implement.  Do I need to add another function to the existing jquery ajax call?

Comment: No. You just need to define what you want to do on click once. If you use jQuery's `.on`, there is no need for a for loop. Check the example I advised above.

Comment: Cheers will give it a go

Comment: Thanks Roman - got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You add event listeners to inital items only, but not on new items after they're added.

You need event propagation, basically you attach event listener to higher element (for example window, body or container of all items) and then on that event listener you check event target's className or whatever.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery's way to do that with using `.on`

So here is how to do it with jQuery, if you wish I can rewrite in plain JS.

```
$('.accordion').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  const panel = $(this).next()
  if (panel.css('maxHeight')) {
    panel.css({ maxHeight: 'null'})
  } else {
    panel.css({ maxHeight: panel[0].scrollHeight + 'px' })
  } 
});
```

There is probably way to get scrollHeight in jquery way but I havent done jQuery for long time, just cant remember.